# статичная мутабельная строка на rust

Tags: строки, rust, static

начал осваивать unsafe режим раста, и задача, казалось бы, проста:

нужна изменяемая строка со статичным временем жизни, что-то вроде

```
let mut LOG_STRING: &'static String;
```

но при именно такой реализации возникает проблема с инициализацией, так как такая строка "имеет меньшее время жизни"

```
LOG_STRING = &String::new();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^- temporary value only lives until here
              |
              does not live long enough
```

как это *можно* сделать? и как это делается *правильно*?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте разберём, что написано в сигнатуре этой переменной:

```
let mut      // изменяемая переменная
    LOG_STRING:
    &       // с неизменяемой ссылкой
    'static // со статическим временем жизни,
            // т.е. живёт на протяжении всей программы
    String; // на объект строки, владеющий буфером
```

Такая комбинация не имеет большого смысла. Вы хотите, по сути, разместить где-то глобальные переменные с владеющими строками и с помощью этой переменной переключаться между ними.

По-моему, вы на самом деле хотите один из двух сценариев

1. Глобальная ссылка на строку, которую можно переключать в зависимости от контекста. Проблема в том, что таким способом крайне легко "отстрелить себе ногу". Вы можете конечно иметь подобный код:

   ```
   let mut LOG_STRING: &'static str;

   // ... somewhere in code
   LOG_STRING = unsafe { &my_String_buffer[..] };
   ```

   Но как только ваш `my_String_buffer` будет удалён, `LOG_STRING` будет указывать в никуда.
2. Глобальная строка, которую вы периодически меняете

   ```
   lazy_static! { static LOG_STRING: Mutex<String> = Mutex::new(String::new()); }
   // ... somewhere in code
   *(LOG_STRING.lock().unwrap()) = "Hellow global string!".to_owned();
   ```

   В этом конкретном случае никакой ансэйф не нужен.

Либо, если у вас какой-то другой сценарий, опишите его подробней.

Comment: сценарий таков: есть 2 потока, один пишет в данную строку какие-либо символы, а второй поток - tcp-сервер, при подключении клиента шлет клиенту содержимое данной строки

Comment: Асинхронная очередь?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/

Если делать "руками" - легко отстрелить себе ногу.

Answer (score 2):

Ты можешь использовать `String`

`let mut LOG_STRING: String;`

Все объекты без явных лайфтаймов имеют время жизни `'static`.

Но это будет не безопасно, т.к. к `static` переменным имеет доступ любой поток, а значит возможна гонка данных.

Чтобы избежать этого, можно воспользовать `thread_local!` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html
Он создаст глобальный для конкретного потока объект.

Если же тебе нужен доступ к объекту из нескольких потоков. То тогда стоит учесть, что обычный `static` не позволит создавать объекты с не константными конструкторами. Например создание `String` требует аллокации памяти на кучи, а значит не может быть создан на этапе компиляции.

Для таких случаев тебе нужна внешняя библиотека `lazy_static!` она позволяет создать объект, который будет про инициализирован при первом обращении. Но для организации общего доступа, тебе веще потребуется `Mutex`

т.е. для глобального объекта в пределах потока:

```
thread_local! {
    pub static FOO: String = String::new();
}
```

И для lazy_static

```
#[macro_use] extern crate lazy_static;
use std::sync::Mutex;
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref FOO:Mutex<String> =  Mutex::new(String::new());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На сегодня для такого "правильно" пользоваться костылем, который уже стал настолько распространенным, что костылем его не считают. Крейт lazy_static для создания такого. Внутри там в нем std::sync::Once.

std::sync::Mutex или что-нибудь похожее - для безопасного доступа с разных потоков.

Так же, запись `let mut a=&b` - это изменяемая ссылка на константу. То есть, так как вы написали - это будет неизменяемая строка. 
Если нужна ссылка на изменяемую переменную, то это `let a = &mut b` - ссылка только на эту переменную, или `let mut a=&mut b` - ссылку можно менять, и переменную можно менять.

Возможно, если вам достаточно только менять ссылки, то имеет смысл обойтись &str. Так как String - это строка в куче, и нужно это только когда нужны преимущества кучи.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получилось нечто такое:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
use std::sync::Mutex;
lazy_static! { pub static ref LOG_STRING: Mutex<String> = Mutex::new(String::new()); }

fn main(){
  ...
  thread::spawn(move || {
    ...
    let response = String::from("[serv]: ".to_owned() + &*(LOG_STRING.lock().unwrap()));
    ...
  });
  ...
}
```